# Display specific records in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a model Page, which has many Parameters. I want to display specific Parameters, based on value of "name" column. What would be the best way to do it?

I am converting all `Page.parametes` to a `hash param[:name] = value`, so in View I can use `<%= param[:name] %>` but this doesn't look good in the Model code.

```
def self.get_real(id)
   params = {}
   data = Parameter.where(page_id: id)
   data.each do |var|
     params[var.parameter.to_sym] = var.value
  end
  params
end
```

Comment: You should not use the keyword `params`, it is a method used in controllers/views to retrieve the `GET` and `POST` parameters. It might lead to conflicts at some point.

Comment: Why would you wanna do that? It's a very bad idea, instead you should be making a variable in controller and use it in view.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the id of the page object then:

*in the controller:*

```
def show # or whatever your action may be
  @page_parameters = Page.find(params[:id]).parameters
end
```

*in the view:*

```
<% @page_parameters.each do |p| %>
  <%= p.name %> : <%= p.value %>
<% end %>
```

I do not see a reason (in this case) to convert an object into a primitive.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to display them in a loop - just specific VALUE in specific place.